# How to show the error details in Qt compile output

Tags: qt, qt-creator

It is really painful to find out which external symbol is missing manually. I did some search on web, but no one has the same issue.

```
link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /OPT:REF /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /VERSION:1.0 /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:release\viewer.exe @C:\Users\deepcyto\AppData\Local\Temp\viewer.exe.17808.2938.jom

datafiletablemodel.obj : error LNK2019: 
release\viewer.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1
```

Comment: Did you try to look at `Compile Output` tab in Qt Creator?

Comment: Yes.  The text "error LNK2019: " was copied from compile output table.

Comment: The Compile Output pane is showing the output of your compiler/linker, basically as it is, so this is not  really a QtCreator issue, but more related to the compiler.  The fact that the error message empty would suggest that something is wrong with your environment. Could you please share some more details about your MSVC version and how did you set it up?